# UIImagePickerController causes viewDidLoad - where to store image data?

Tags: iphone

I found that `UIImagePickerController` can unload your parent view, especially if you bring up the camera, resulting in viewDidLoad being called again. I understand that this happens due to low memory. But I was storing the `UIImage*` from  `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` in the view controller. This data is lost after a reload. (The `self` pointer for the view controller has changed, and the `UIImage*` is null.) So is it a bad idea to store such variables in the view controller? Where should they be stored - in a global (singleton) object?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really good advice to actually solve your problem, but ignoring the memory warning will in this case help a lot:

```
-(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // we're too important to get flushed out by our child imagepicker.
}
```

in your view controller will solve this.

A place to store objects you really need, could be the app delegate, since it will not unload on memory warnings. (any place not responding to memory warnings will do)